# "Stealth" class to enclose a variable in C++

Tags: c++, class, arduino, wrapper

I'm currently using two identical libraries for parsing commands received in Arduino (via [TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) and via Serial). All the difference is in the object type being passed to the parser.

```
//main.cpp
SerCmd sCmd;
EthCmd eCmd;
void setup() {
    sCmd.listen("#",dumpCmd);
    eCmd.listen("#",dumpCmd);
}

void loop() {
    HardwareSerial SerClient = Serial.available();
    EthernetClient EthClient = Server.available();
    eCmd.read(SerClient);
    sCmd.read(EthClient);
}


//SerCmd.h
class SerCmd {
    public:
        void read(HardwareSerial &dataObj);
}

//EthCmd.h
class EthCmd {
    public:
        void read(EthernetClient &dataObj);
}
```

It's obvious that:

- The two objects are nearly identical, and they share lots of common methods (sCmd, eCd).
- The two classes (SerCmd, EthCmd) can be replaced with a single class to reduce the [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch) size.

How can I create a "stealth" class which could be passed to the `read()` method, while still addressing any of the two different objects underneath?

What's the common practice used in such situations?

So far, I am able to compile the below code, but cannot initialize any methods:

```
class Communication {};
HardwareSerial *SerClient;
Communication *Comm;

void setup() {
    Comm = (Communication*) SerClient;
    //Comm.begin(9600);
    //Error: request for member 'print' in 'Comm',
    //which is of non-class type 'Communication*'
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of inheritance?

Comment: About the code: you should use `->` instead of `.` since `Comm` is a pointer.

Comment: IMHO class `Communication` should be an abstract base class for `HardwareSerial` and `EthernetClient` to achieve what you want ...

Comment: There are three basic approaches: dynamic polymorphism (inheritance using the template method pattern), static polymorphism (templates), and the strategy and command design patterns. You can also judiciously combine the three.

Comment: Alright, thanks. These keywords is exactly what I've been looking for.